# Break tie function js

Tags: javascript, function, tie

I'm learning JS and I'm making an app to find the winners per hole in a golf game. The player with less strokes is the winner of the hole, but sometimes more than one player could tie the hole with the same number strokes, so, to find the winner of the hole I need to evaluate the number of strokes from the tied players in the next hole and break the tie, if the tie persist, I need to evaluate the next hole and so on.

The function foo should return an array with the index, position or names from the winner or winners of the hole (if the tie was impossible to break).

Here's my code:

```
var players = [
    "Jug 1",
    "Jug 2",
    "Jug 3",
    "Jug 4"
];

var arrHoyos = [
    [4, 3, 3, 4],
    [4, 5, 4, 5],
    [4, 4, 5, 6]
];

function foo(array) {
    var arrWinners = [];
    //arrHoyos
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        var arr = array[i];
        var arr2 = array[(i + 1) % array.length];
        var pos = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var tie = false;
        var temp = [];
        var temp2 = [];
        min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
        //arr
        for (var j = 0, len2 = arr.length; j < len2; j++) {
            if (min == arr[j]) {
                temp.push(arr.indexOf(min, j));
            }   
        }
        if (temp.length > 1) {
            tie = true;
            var counter = 0;
            while (tie == true) {
                for (var count = 0; count < temp.length; count++) {
                    pos = temp[count];
                    temp2[count] = arr2[pos];
                }
                min = Math.min.apply(null, temp2);
                for (var count2 = 0; count2 < temp.length; count2++) {
                    if (temp2[count2] != min) {
                        temp.slice(count2, 1);
                    }
                }
                if (temp.length == 1 || counter == array.length) {
                    tie = false;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        arrWinners[i] = players[temp[0]];
        console.log(temp, temp2);
        console.log(arrWinners[i]);
    }
}

foo(arrHoyos);
```

Chrome console result:

```
[1, 2] [5, 4]
Jug 2
[0, 2] [4, 5]
Jug 1
[0, 1] [4, 3]
Jug 1
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code as it is now?

Comment: It is incomplete, I just get the positions (index) of the best scores per hole. I need to connect the value of those positions (temp) and the values of those index in the next hole (array) to break the actual tie and left temp array with just one index.

Comment: can you use a second array for the information for the next hole?

Comment: Yep, I'm using temp2 to save the score values from the temp positions. I'm sorry, where can I post the Chrome console results of the code? I'm really noob here.

Comment: Edit your question, add the error output, format it as code.

Comment: Those are the results, as you can see, I think I'm in the right way, but the winner player is wrong.

Comment: What should be the output?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you are using `slice` instead of `splice`. May have even been a typo. You are probably not increasing the whole index when using `temp2` inside while loop. I have a feeling that it is always the next hole.

Side notes/recommendations:

1. Learn to use debugger.
2. Use meaningful names for variables. `temp`, `temp2`, `arr` and others are not good.

EDIT: include actual code with correct `splice` use

```
var players = [
    "Jug 1",
    "Jug 2",
    "Jug 3",
    "Jug 4"
];

var arrHoyos = [
    [4, 3, 3, 4],
    [4, 5, 4, 5],
    [4, 4, 5, 6]
];

function foo(array) {
    var arrWinners = [];
    //arrHoyos
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        var arr = array[i];
        var arr2 = array[(i + 1) % array.length];
        var pos = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var tie = false;
        var temp = [];
        var temp2 = [];
        min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
        //arr
        for (var j = 0, len2 = arr.length; j < len2; j++) {
            if (min == arr[j]) {
                temp.push(arr.indexOf(min, j));
            }   
        }
        if (temp.length > 1) {
            tie = true;
            var counter = 0;
            while (tie == true) {
                for (var count = 0; count < temp.length; count++) {
                    pos = temp[count];
                    temp2[count] = arr2[pos];
                }

                min = Math.min.apply(null, temp2);
                for (var count2 = 0; count2 < temp.length; count2++) {
                    if (temp2[count2] != min) {
                        temp.splice(count2, 1);
                    }
                }
                if (temp.length == 1 || counter == array.length) {
                    tie = false;
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
        arrWinners[i] = players[temp[0]];
        console.log(temp, temp2);
        console.log(arrWinners[i]);
    }
}

foo(arrHoyos);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll watch a couple of videos of debugging and try to fix it.

Comment: Great, the 'splice' works fine, I'll test what happens when the ties is impossible to break. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, thank you Danil, your help was useful. :)

```
var players = [
    "Jug 1",
    "Jug 2",
    "Jug 3",
    "Jug 4"
];

var arrFieldStrokes = [
    [3, 3, 3, 3],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [5, 6, 5, 5],
    [5, 7, 6, 5],
    [4, 5, 5, 4],
    [4, 5, 6, 8],
    [4, 6, 6, 5],
    [4, 5, 9, 5],
    [4, 4, 4, 4]
];

function breakTie(hole, arrTiedPlayers, arrField) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrField.length; i++) {
        var min = 0, count = 0; arrNextScore = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < arrTiedPlayers.length; j++) {
            arrNextScore[j] = arrField[(hole + i + 1) % arrField.length][arrTiedPlayers[j]];
        }
        min = Math.min.apply(null, arrNextScore);
        count = arrNextScore.length;
        while (count--) {
            if (arrNextScore[count] != min) {
                arrTiedPlayers.splice(count, 1);
            }
        }
        if (arrTiedPlayers.length == 1) {
            return players[arrTiedPlayers[0]];
        }
    }
    var tiePlayers = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < arrTiedPlayers.length; c++) {
        tiePlayers[c] = players[arrTiedPlayers[c]];
    }
    return tiePlayers;
}

function winners(arrField) {
    var arrWinners = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrField.length; i++) {
        var min = 0, arrTiedPlayers = [];
        min = Math.min.apply(null, arrField[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < arrField[i].length; j++) {
            if (arrField[i][j] == min) {
                arrTiedPlayers.push(arrField[i].indexOf(min, j));
            }
        }
        if (arrTiedPlayers.length == 1) {
            arrWinners[i] = players[arrTiedPlayers[0]];
            console.log("Hoyo-" + (i + 1) + " Winner: " + arrWinners[i]);
        }
        else {
            arrWinners[i] = breakTie(i, arrTiedPlayers, arrField);
            console.log("Hoyo-" + (i + 1) + " Winner: " + arrWinners[i]);
        }
    }
}

winners(arrFieldStrokes);
```